Android D8 Gives java error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid invocation
Hello i am trying to install Android build tools with Android Command Line Tools but when i run d8.bat it gives this error below in command prompt:
C:\Users>

C:\Users>d8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid invocation.
Usage: d8 [options] [@<argfile>] <input-files>
 where <input-files> are any combination of dex, class, zip, jar, or apk files
 and each <argfile> is a file containing additional arguments (one per line)
 and options are:
  
               *** all d8 settings here ****

        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.2.2-dev_53a55043254cc5be8ef500331bba25d1b4ca4bc2cd66c555d4358bf672a1f10a:7)

Using Microsoft OpenJDK 21:
C:\Users>java -version
openjdk version "21.0.5" 2024-10-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-10377968 (build 21.0.5+11-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-10377968 (build 21.0.5+11-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
C:\Users>

How Can i solve this

d8 simply tells you that your command-line arguments are wrong. Only that it uses a Java exception for doing so is   bit unusual...
